# How do I (consistently, systematically, theoretically) extend my website's base colors scheme?

Tags: color, color-theory

I am using the following basic RGB color scheme for my website:

43/66/79

84/129/156

79/68/43

156/122/84

176/176/176

79/79/79

I would like to extend the pallette, but not in a random way. I would like to apply known theories of how that is systematically done.

Can someone refer me to reading on the subject, or perhaps even better, places on the net that allows me to enter the base colors and receive suggestions on extentions.

Comment: Do you want colors or numbers?

Comment: @Danielillo ideally RGB numbers.

Comment: Hi user120911, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. I downvoted your post because I think you need to give us some more information. What is the palette used for? A website? An e-book? Pixel art? All of those would ask for wildly different answers. Please [edit] your question to give us some more information about the use case, and you might get some good, usable asnwers. Thanks!

Comment: If you have any questions about this site or the Stack Exchange model in general, have a look at the [help] or the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) respectively. They will get you up to speed about how this site works and what is on and off topic. Keep contributing and enjoy learning from and with us all!

Comment: Besides, would it be possible for you to post an image of your palette? I am a visual kind of person and I cannot judge how colours look just by looking at numbers. I would be surprised if I were the only one here. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need 6 colors, I think anything over 2-3 is too many, but assuming you have your reasons, look at [Kuler's existing color sets](https://color.adobe.com/explore/?filter=most-popular&time=month). This should be more than enough to get some useful ideas. There are also alot of similar questions here which you can go through, see the 'Related' tab on the right.